# Zeros of an analytic function

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to prove zeros of a real analytic function (non-zero function) is always countable?

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that the zeros are isolated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ have an uncountable number of zeros. Assume that each disk $D_n=\{z:|z|\leq n\}$ contains only a finite number of zeros of $f(z)$. Call the set of these zeros $A_n=\{z\in D_n: f(z)=0\}$. Then the set of all zeros of $f$ is $$A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$$ is countable, at most. This is a contradiction, so there exists $D_n$ which contains an infinite set $A_n$. Since $D_n$ is compact, $A_n$ has a limit point. Since the zeros of analytic functions cannot have limit points, $f$ is not analytic.